# Installing Web helpers library with nuget

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget, helper

It works fine if i create a new project, and install it on that, but doing it with the project i am working on i get this error:

I have tried replacing all the dll files, packages.xml, web.config.
with the the files from before i installed web helpers, but the problem is still there.

This line of code (line 50), that now shows an error is exactly the same, and worked fine before the installation.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The connection name 'DefaultConnection' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.

Source Error: 


Line 48:     <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
Line 49:       <providers>
Line 50:         <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
Line 51:       </providers>
Line 52:     </membership>

Source File: C:\Users\BJARKE\Desktop\OlabsRepositories\iconbench\IconBench\web.config    Line: 50 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17626
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is going to solve your problem, but I had the same issue and I fixed it adding these 2 lines to web.config under appsettings

```
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false"/>
```

Good luck
Matteo

Comment: Thank you! Will give it a try later!